# Get defaultUserRolePermissions using microsoft graph api

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get details of defaultUserRolePermissions resource type through Microsoft graph Api.
I want that data shown in image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get **default user role permissions** using Microsoft Graph API, you can run below graph query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/policies/authorizationPolicy?$select=defaultUserRolePermissions
```

I have these **settings** configured for the users in my directory:

[image]

When I ran below query in **[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)** with **`Policy.Read.All`** permissions, I got **required details** successfully in response like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/policies/authorizationPolicy?$select=defaultUserRolePermissions
```

**Response:**

[image]

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#policies/authorizationPolicy(defaultUserRolePermissions)",
    "value": [
        {
            "defaultUserRolePermissions": {
                "allowedToCreateApps": true,
                "allowedToCreateSecurityGroups": true,
                "allowedToCreateTenants": true,
                "allowedToReadBitlockerKeysForOwnedDevice": true,
                "allowedToReadOtherUsers": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Reference:**
[Get authorizationPolicy - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authorizationpolicy-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Comment: Thanks ,It helps me. Can we get other properties as well like Administration center,LinkedIn account connections,External collaboration settings

Comment: AFAIK, only few properties are supported to manage via Graph API. Other properties like Administration center, LinkedIn account connections, External collaboration settings are not yet available. Refer similar case [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/551519/possibility-of-changing-user-settings-in-azure-ad)

Comment: @Sridevi  These properties are also not available in Powershell Graph ?

Comment: No, they are not available in PowerShell Graph too

Comment: We can't even get Administration center properties through any api ?

Comment: No. AFAIK, we can get only few properties like defaultUserRolePermissions via API.

Comment: can we get Microsoft 365 admin center -> organization settings properties through any API ?

Comment: Could you post a new question regarding this by including the screenshot of what you exactly want?

Comment: No ,unable to post new question because of stackoverflow conditions

Comment: can u plz reply here ? How to get Microsoft 365 AdminCenter  -> organization setting properties ?